# store photo library images in cache or file path ios

Tags: iphone, ios

click on the button I have got images using assestlibrary framework in ios, and got all images , but click on the button more than 2-3 times , application became slow or crashed because of more than 150 photos retrieved.Is there any code such that i can get image path o cache of photo library image so application run smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. In the end rather then storing the image in memory we saved the ALAssetUrl in an array. So whenever you want to work with an image you pull it out of the asset library using its url.

```
-(void)storeAssetInArray:(ALAsset *)asset {
    _assetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [_assetArray addObject:[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];
}

-(void)getImageBackOut {
    [ALAssetsLibrary assetForURL:[_assetArray objectAtIndex:0] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        if (asset) {
            [self getTheImage:uploadImage Asset:asset];
        }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
        //Failed to get asset
    } ];
}

-(void)getTheImage:(UploadImage *)uploadImage Asset:(ALAsset *)asset {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]];
}
```

Comment: hii, On button click,how should i logout from instagram in ios ?

Comment: I'm not sure I haven't worked with Instagram before. If you are using there api just read there documentation http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/ :)

Comment: can you please give me your code for storing URL of image of photo library ?

Comment: There you go because I'm just such a nice guy :P